# Neo4j Embedded HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create embedded HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase. My server configurations,

```
ha.server_id=1
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.9.1:5001,192.168.9.2:5002,192.168.9.3:5003
ha.server=192.168.9.1:6002
ha.cluster_server=192.168.9.1:5001

ha.server_id=2
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.9.1:5001,192.168.9.2:5002,192.168.9.3:5003
ha.server=192.168.9.2:6002
ha.cluster_server=192.168.9.2:5002

ha.server_id=3
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.9.1:5001,192.168.9.2:5002,192.168.9.3:5003
ha.server=192.168.9.3:6002
ha.cluster_server=192.168.9.3:5003
```

In my java class I create the database as follows,

```
public class HighAvailableDbTest
{
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    private static Map<String, String> haConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory databaseFactory = new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory();

       haConfig.put("org.neo4j.server.database.mode", "HA");
       haConfig.put("org.neo4j.server.webserver.address","0.0.0.0");
       haConfig.put("CONFIG_KEY_HA_MACHINE_ID","1");
       haConfig.put("CONFIG_KEY_HA_SERVER", "192.168.9.1:6002");


        graphDb = new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()
      .newHighlyAvailableDatabaseBuilder("test.db")
      .setConfig(haConfig)
      .newGraphDatabase();

    }
 }
```

But when I run the code, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: indexProviders
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:47)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197).
```

Help me!!.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a version conflict in your java classpath. Please check that you have only neo4j libraries of a single version configured. (e.g. mvn dependency:tree)

Comment: You invoke the constructor of HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory twice. That could also cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a simple dummy project that shows how two embedded neo4j databases can be setup to work in HA mode.

https://github.com/Jotschi/neo4j-ha-example